# Spring MVC. Why resources are not visible from JSP page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have simple spring mvc app. I try to add CSS like static resource to my app, but my jsp page can't find it.

My jsp page look this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><fmt:message key="app.title"/></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
         ..................................................................
    </body>
    </html>
```

Also my spring-mvc context look this:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="ru.javawebinar.**.web"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp"/>
```

And my resources are located this:

[image]

Comment: Please post code as code not as images.

Comment: What URL do you open your JSP page? I think it supposed to be a relative or absolute path problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JSTL? if so  you can include like this.

```
 <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

another way is:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes:

In spring-web-config.xml:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css/"/>
```

In your jsp file:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

**UPDATE:**

For Spring you can try in your *.jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title><fmt:message key="app.title"/></title>
    <spring:url value="/resources/css/style.css" var="mainCss" />
    <link href="${mainCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    ..................................................................
  </body>
</html>
```